# Grids - Action Column to behave like a Flyout Menu

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm using ExtJS for my project and can see that there is a way to embed "actioncolumns" inside of Grid columns. However, my "action" isn't just a single click, it actually needs to show a flyout menu (similar to the Menu control). Is there a direct way to do this in Ext? Or do I have to implement all this functionality myself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a menu in a grid - ExtJS 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945026/how-to-show-a-menu-in-a-grid-extjs-5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way. You need to create a menu and show it manually in the event handler for action button. You can also show menu as a context menu for the grid (right click).

Comment: Another response sha. Thanks mate. I thought it would be something trivial like that but thought I'd ask just in case :)